# How to change colour of a line with click of a button?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am able to change colour of a line ,like this :-

```
Pen P1 = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3);
PointF pt1 = new PointF(450.0F, 60.0F);
PointF pt2 = new PointF(20.0F, 60.0F);
e.Graphics.DrawLine(P1, pt1, pt2);
```

But, I am not able to change the colour of a line with a button's click.

Please tell how to change the colour of a line with click of a button, in windows form, visual studio, in c#.

Comment: Create a class variable for the Color. In the buttons click event handler assign a color to that variable. And in the shown code use the variable instead of the hardcoded Color.Blue.

Comment: As mentioned above, create a separate variable for the color used for painting, and then put the modification code in the button. You can create a public variable. Choose whether to use the Invalidate and update methods according to your needs.

Comment: please explain little more

Answer (score 1):

Create a field of type `Pen` and initialize its `Color` to color you want and in `Button`'s `Click` event handler, change the color of the pen and `Invalidate` the client area of the `Form` to trigger a paint event.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        InitializeComponent();
        m_pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2.0f);
    }
    private Pen m_pen = null;
    
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
         base.OnPaint(e);
         e.Graphics.DrawLine(m_pen, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         m_pen.Color = Color.Blue;
         Invalidate(); 
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried this code.., but colour of line is still not changing through button..

Comment: You forgot to add the method `button1_Click` to the `Click` event handler of  your `Button`.

Comment: it's there in the code:-                                                                                           private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_pen.Color = Color.Blue;
            Invalidate();
        }

Comment: `button1.Click += button1_Click;` ?

Comment: sorry i did not understand......you have not written this (        button1.Click += button1_Click;           
  ) in your code.

Comment: Because you should write it.

Comment: i wrote , then also it did not change

Comment: please help, what to add more

Comment: Friend, I have provided all the necessary code but you cannot even adopt it to your project. Please review your favourite C#/Winforms tutorial.